# Adapt existing code for OpenGL stereoscopic rendering?

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to implement stereoscopic 3d in OpenGL using a side-by-side technique.

I've read [this article](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/miscellaneous/stereographics/stereorender/) which in great detail explains how to set up the camera for left and right views. It uses a camera model and set up the left and right views using gluLookAt.

However in my case I want to **adapt existing code that already set up the projection**.

See the following example where "existingcode" represents the code that I cannot make changes to.

```
//Render left view

// setUpCamera set the gl projection and model matrix
existingcode.setUpCamera()

..
here I want to somehow modify the current gl projection matrix for the left view
..

existingcode.renderScene()

//.. then render right view
```

Can it be done, perhaps by calling glGetMatrix and modify it somehow?

Comment: Does your existing code clear the projection matrix (using glLoadIdentify) ? Or does it compose its projection matrix with the top of the stack ?

Comment: The existing code reset the stack using glLoadIdentity but I could possibly prevent it from doing that. Why, do you have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've to do is employ some lens shiftig.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
stereo_offset = eye * near * parallax_factor / convergence_distance;
glFrustum(stereo_offset + left, stereo_offset + right, bottom, top, near, far);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(eye * parallax_factor * convergence_distance, 0, 0);

/* now use gluLookAt here as this were a normal 2D rendering */
```

`parallax_factor` should be no larger than the ratio of half_eye_distance / screen_width, so the larger the screen gets the smaller the parallax_factor is. A good value for parallax_factor for computer display use is 0.05, for large screens (think cinema) it's something like 0.01

This projection shifting technique is exactly what I used for re-rendering **Elephants Dream** in stereoscopic 3D, although, since Blenders offline renderer doesn't use OpenGL the code looks a little bit different http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-tmaMR1p3w

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however the article I refer to also describes how to render when you have control over the camera. In my case the code that setup the camera is in a piece of code that is already written and preferably not be changed. So my question is whether it is possible to modify the camera after glFrustum etc is already called. Or maybe I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: Do you have access to the code? If so, then the changes are minimal. You just have to modify the way glFrustum is called (right where it happens). You can leave all the modelview matrix operations the same, you just have to apply a initial translation to them. The total changes will boil down to at most 10 lines of code.

Comment: The existing code calls gluPerspective instead of glFrustum and I was hoping to find a non-intrusive technique that avoids changing the  camera code, but your answer is helpful anyway and I will use that solution if nothing else appears here.

Comment: gluPerspective is easy enough to replace with glFrustum: stereoscopicPerspective(float fov, float aspect, float near, float far, stereo_offset) { float const baselength = 0.5 * near * tanf(M_PI * fov / 180.); glFrustum(stereo_offset - aspect * baselength, stereo_offset + aspect * baselength, -baselength, baselength, near, far); } -- there you are.

Comment: Thanks again, I think I'm getting it to work now. Do you have any references on the web from where you gained that knowledge? I would like to understand the details.

Comment: @Ville Krumlinde: Most of my knowledge about stereoscopic rendering stems from my own experiments and experiences. I got my first pair of shutter glasses 12 years ago and have been experimenting with them ever since. I've read a few articles (don't ask me which ones or when, because I don't remember) and from there developed my own techniques. ATM I'm writing an exhaustive book about realtime rendering techniques with OpenGL, something like the SuperBible but with a diffrent structure and didactics. It will also contain a large section about stereoscopy.